# Doesn't this graph on a torus have characteristic 2?

Tags: general-topology

I don't know much about topology, but I'm reading [this article](http://www.hypocritereader.com/59/surfaces-of-things) which claims

> A graph on the torus has Euler characteristic 0.

Isn't this a counter-example? It looks like $\chi=V-E+F=1-1+2=2$ as it would on a sphere.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this be true for every tiny loop on a sufficiently small area of any topology? Use an alternative definition $\chi=2-2g$ from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Relations_to_other_invariants), where $g$ are the "handles"...

Comment: Exactly my point. As for your formula, we have $g=1$ in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The statement

> Every graph on a torus has characteristic 0.

Isn't correct, as your example, or indeed any planar graph drawn on a small, flat fragment of a torus shows. A correct formulation requires us to add one more assumption on the drawing of the graph, namely - all faces are homeomorphic to a disk. In your example this isn't the case, since the large, white face can't be continuously deformed into a disk.